# Getting IllegalState with ReactiveMongoTemplate : No thread-bound request found

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Using ReactiveMongoTemplate to for Crud op, when executing following code snippet

```
return reactiveMongoTemplate.findOne(filterQuery, MongoDocDetails.class
                            , ServiceConstants.COLLECTION_NAME).flatMap(
                            existingDocument -> updateExistingDocument(existingDocument, newDocRequest))
                    .switchIfEmpty(createNewDocument(newDocRequest));
```

getting following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.requestLabels': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:373)

at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:113)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
```

my controller, service and repository function are having Mono<> return type.

I have been able to deduce the part related to flatMap() is breaking . so i have also tried following approach but no success

```
return reactiveMongoTemplate.findOne(filterQuery, MongoDocDetails.class
                    , ServiceConstants.COLLECTION_NAME).map(existingDocument -> {
                        if(existingDocument != null){
                            return updateExistingDocument(existingDocument, newDocRequest);
                        } else {
                            return createNewDocument(newDocRequest);
                        }
            } ).flatMap(result -> result);
```

**But if** i use a simple ternary blocking operation instead of following non-blocking reactive approach mentioned above, it works

```
var mongoExistingDocument = reactiveMongoTemplate.findOne(filterQuery, MongoDocDetails.class
                            , ServiceConstants.COLLECTION_NAME).blocked();
var docID = mongoExistingDocument != null ? updateExistingDocument(existingDocument, newDocRequest): createNewDocument(newDocRequest);
```

Please provide you inputs if any

thanks in advance.